# aws api gateway file upload with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, jwt

I'm making api for web application and we are using aws api gateway with aws lambda and now i need to upload files via that API somehow.

Lambda function checks, if user logged in or not, by verifying JWT token. It is really necessary. Also JWT contains info about user role etc.

First thing that comes to my mind - convert every file on client side to base64, and then decode it on server side and save it to S3, but it doesn't seems the right way.

Can somebody advise me the better way how to upload files via AWS gateway and AWS lambda